# Regex that considers custom escape characters in the string (not in the pattern)

Tags: python, regex

I'm building a regex that must match a certain pattern that starts with a specific symbol, but at the same time it must not match a pattern that starts with two or more occurrences of that same specific symbol.

To elaborate better, this is my scenario. I have a string like this:

```
Hello %partials/footer/mail,
%no_slashes_here
%{using_braces}_here
%%should_not_be_matched
```

And I'm trying to match those substrings that start with exactly one `%` symbol (since in my case a double `%%` means "escaping" and should not be matched) and they could optionally be surrounded by curly braces. And at the end, I need to capture the matched substrings but without the `%` symbol.

So far my regular expression is:

```
%\{*([0-9a-zA-Z_/]+)\}*
```

And the captured matches result is:

```
partials/footer/mail
no_slashes_here
using_braces
should_not_be_matched
```

Which is very close to what I need, but I got stuck into the double `%%` escaping part. I don't know how to negate two or more `%` symbols at the beginning and at the same time allow exactly one occurrence at the beginning too.

**EDIT:**
Sorry that I missed that, I'm using python.

Comment: What regex flavour are you using? A [negative lookbehind would help here](https://regex101.com/r/pP5mX6/1), but it's not available in all languages.

Comment: I'm using python. Just edited the question.

Comment: Not a language I'm familiar with I'm afraid so can't advise either way - feel free to try the regex I linked to...!

Comment: Are the substrings always to the end of the line or multiline?

Comment: This is a multiline string and the substrings can be anywhere

Comment: If it is multiline, what is the definitive start of and end of the capture then?

Comment: dawg, if the match is `%something`, I need the final capture to be `something`

Comment: I understand that, but what about `%line1\nline2\n%line3\nline4%something else`?

Comment: Ah I see, the start must be the `%` symbol and the pattern must stop when it finds the first character that is neither of: number, letter, underscore or slash. In the case of the string you specified, the captures must be: `line`, `line3` and `something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With negative lookbehind:

```
%(?<!%%)\{*([0-9a-zA-Z_\/]+)\}*
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/xM4nW6/2)

Comment: Mmm, it is still matching "should_not_be_matched"

Comment: This one is working pretty well with the test string above. I'll test it with more cases.

Comment: Marco, thanks a lot man, I found that this regex worked great for the rest of my cases. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If this is line based -- you can do:

```
(?:^|[^%])%\{?([^%}]+)\}?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJ4jC6/2)

Python demo:

```
txt='''\
Hello %partials/footer/mail,
%no_slashes_here
%{using_braces}_here
%%should_not_be_matched
This %% niether'''

import re

for line in txt.splitlines():
    m=re.search(r'(?:^|[^%])%\{?([^%}]+)\}?', line)
    if m:
        print m.group(1)
```

It is unclear from your question how `% this % should be treated`

Comment: yes, you're right `% this %` should not be matched and stay as it is. But the regex in my post thankfully handles this situation.

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
(?<=%)([^%]+)
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU2fS1/3)

I've assumed PCRE, as you've not declared which flavour of Regex you're using.